# Какой sql-запрос в Oracle будет быстрее: через in или через join?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, производительность

Подскажите, если запрашивать подобными селектами большие объемы данных (в текстовом формате - под 100 мегабайт), какой вариант запроса будет выполняться в oracle быстрее: через `in` или через `join`?

Примеры двух таких запросов с одинаковым результатом:

```
--1) using "in" operator 
select *
from table3
where table3.table1__id in (
        select table1.id
        from table1
        where table1.table2__oid in (
                select table2.id
                from table2
                where table2.idt in (820827, 820894, 820725, 820899)
                )
        );

--2) using "join" 
select table3.*
from table1, table2, table3
where table1.table2__oid = table2.id
    and table3.table1__id = table1.id
    and table2.idt in (820827, 820894, 820725, 820899);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На такой вопрос не может быть однозначного ответа. Оптимизатор `Oracle` может переписывать запросы для поиска оптимального плана выполнения. В вашем случае запрос достаточно простой, по этому оптимизатор скорее всего успеет найти оптимальный план дня него.

**Чтобы сравнить два запроса с точки зрения производительности надо смотреть не на текст запроса, а на его план.** 
Без плана запроса сложно сравнивать производительность.

**PS**

Однако стоит помнить, что оптимизатор может физически не успеть перебрать всевозможные планы запросов за отведенное ему для этого время.  В связи с этим большое количество вложенных запросов может работать медленнее. 
Когда заранее известно, что подзапрос вернет большое количество строк, имеет смысл переписать запрос используя join.

Comment: @idrakonl, спасибо! А когда вложенных таблиц значительно больше? 5-10? Если какая-то общая рекомендация как лучше/правильнее писать?

Comment: Я стараюсь писать используя `join`, чтобы уменьшить количество вложенных запросов, однако универсального ответа когда как лучше писать я дать не могу. Однако потенциально большое количество вложенных запросов может замедлить время выполнения запроса, если оптимизатор не успеет переписать план запроса.

Comment: @777Julia777 Общая рекомендация одна - смотрите план выполнения запросов по `explain plan` и если он вас не устраивает, пробуйте переписать запрос или добавить в него подсказки оптимизатора

Comment: @777Julia777, могу очень порекомендовать [эту книгу](https://www.amazon.com/Cost-Based-Oracle-Fundamentals-Experts-Voice/dp/1590596366) (правда не знаю - существует ли перевод на русский и какого он качества) - хорошо помогает понять как "мыслит" CBO, на основании какой информации он принимает решения и в каких случаях ему надо помогать...