# Как ускорить время выполнения запроса?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, запрос

как можно ускорить данный запрос:

```
SELECT id, surname,
CASE
    WHEN ball < 60 THEN 'Низкий'
    WHEN ball BETWEEN 60 AND 80 THEN 'Средний'
    WHEN ball > 80 THEN 'Высокий'
    END BALL
FROM table1

INTERSECT

SELECT id, surname, 
CASE
    WHEN ball < 60 THEN 'Низкий'
    WHEN ball BETWEEN 60 AND 80 THEN 'Средний'
    WHEN ball > 80 THEN 'Высокий'
    END BALL
FROM table2;
```

Выводит данные тех студентов, информация о которых содержится в обеих таблицах , с помощью запроса-пересечения. А также описание их баллов.

Comment: Для начала посмотреть план выполнения запроса (explain plan). Нельзя оптимизировать что то, если не известно как оно сейчас работает. Если индексы не используются попробовать переписать на join. По крайней мере по id индекс вполне может быть использован

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741003/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-oracle-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-in-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-join/741007#741007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присоединяюсь к комментарию выше. Как минимум:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.surname,  
CASE  
    WHEN t1.ball < 60 THEN 'Низкий'  
    WHEN t1.ball BETWEEN 60 AND 80 THEN 'Средний'  
    WHEN t1.ball > 80 THEN 'Высокий'  
    END BALL  
FROM table1 t1,  
table2 t2  
where t1.id = t2.id
```

`ID` - скорее всего первичный ключ, а он уже индексирован по умолчанию.